# Control over connection used in HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, networking, web-crawler

Is it possible to have any sort of control over the connection used for a HttpWebRequest?  I use the BindIPEndPointDelegate property to set the IP to bind the request to.  However I want to have 5 keep-alive connections that get round-robined through that all use different IPs.

Or is there some sort of way I could contextualize/compartmentalize the connections so that I can say "use this keep-alive connection" specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like setting the ConnectionGroupName property on the HttpWebRequests pools the connections keyed on that string.